# How to apply find.all() using bs4 in Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, beautifulsoup

I am converting the dataframe into table, after that I am trying to find out the `<tr></tr>` inside the table tag , the problem is accuring with the `<tr></tr>` inside the table body. Although the same code is working on the localhost but when deploying it is making problem with the  it is not applying on that . When I am trying to access the `<tr></tr>` inside the table head there it is working perfectly but not in the table body.

**Here inside the find("thead").find_all('tr') it is working here in this part of the code**

```
 for j in soup.find("thead").find_all('tr'):
```

**But When I am trying to access**

```
 if soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr') is not None: #but here it gives us None_type tbody tag #soup not finding tbody tag
```

**This gives us None_type tbody tag #soup not finding tbody tag**

This is the complete code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(sorted_df.to_html(), "html.parser")
        count = 0
        for j in soup.find("thead").find_all('tr'):
            if count == 0:
                j.append(BeautifulSoup('<td><b><center>Next Result</center></b></td>', 'html.parser'))
                count += 1
            else:
                j.append(BeautifulSoup('<td></td>', 'html.parser'))


        modal_identifier = 0
        print(soup,"HERE") #here it shows that soup has tbody tag in it
        job_card = 0
        if soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr') is not None: #but here it gives us None_type tbody tag #soup not finding tbody tag
            i = 0
            while ((soup.find_all("tr")) is not None) and i < len(soup.find_all('tr')):
                temp = soup.find_all('tr')[i].find('th').text
                print(temp, "TEMP")
                soup.find_all('tr')[i].append(BeautifulSoup(
                    '<td><button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal' + str(
                    modal_identifier) + '">Stations Detail</button><div class="modal fade" id="myModal' + str(
                    modal_identifier) + '" role="dialog"><div class="modal-dialog"><div class="modal-content"><div class="modal-header"><button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button><h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4></div><div class="modal-body"><h4>All Station & Timing</h4><p>' + str(
                    testing2[int(temp)]) + '</p><p>' + str(
                    testing3[int(temp)]) + '</p><p>' '</p><h4>Number Of Service Station</h4><p>' + str(
                    numberOfServiceStation[int(temp)]) + '</p><h4>Service Station Name & Timing</h4><p>' + str(
                    stationName[str(temp)]) + '</p><p>' + str(stationTime[int(
                    temp)]) + '</p></div><div class="modal-footer"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button></div></div></div></div></td>',
                'html.parser'))
                i += 1
                modal_identifier += 1
                job_card += 1
```

**The same code is working on the localhost but not on the cloud server**

Comment: Are you sure it is not getting inside the if statement, bs4 is working fine for me applied to exemplary dataframe. Please debug the code and tell me.

Comment: @adnanmuttaleb I am sure because i have commented and run the code . on localhost this is working extremely good but not on the server

Comment: `trs = soup.find('tbody').find_all('tr')`  and then check  `if trs:` then do your actions

Comment: leme check this with @ManaliKagathara

Comment: not working! I have tried this